# pg: ON CONFLICT DO ... ASSERT? ... CHECK?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm dealing with 256bit IDs (blockchain hashes). To save on space, I've decided that 128bits is enough uniqueness so I'm splitting the hash:

```
hash_id BYTEA NOT NULL,
hash_rest BYTEA NOT NULL,
```

`hash_id` is my primary key, and `hash_rest` is just additional data. This way other columns can reference this table by just 16 bytes, instead of 32.

However, I'd like to reliably detect a condition in which I would try to insert data that for which my assumption (128bit prefix being unique) is not try. I'm thinking about something like:

```
INSERT INTO ... ON CONFLICT (hash_id) DO ASSERT hash_rest = EXCLUDED.hash_rest
```

If there's even a way to achieve it, the next step challange is... I might need use that constrain in combination with existing constrain (I sometimes update some timestamps with `ON CONFLICT (hash_id) DO UPDATE timestamp = now()`.

Comment: the bytes you are worried about wasting are negligible more expensive in a server environment. where is your software running?

Comment: @dpc.pw . . . I just don't follow your initial premise.  You are reducing the size of a 32-byte field to a 16-byte field.  In the modern world, that just doesn't seem worth additional effort.

Comment: I am Indexing Bitcoin blockchain. This is mainly personal project. This key is going to be referenced a lot. From couple of tables with more than billion records each. Each byte I can strip from the key saves me more than 4GBs. So this trick is saving me more than 64GB, which is nice when I do it locally.

Comment: Anyway, I'm interested if this can be done, or not. I do realize that I can just not do it, but that's not what I'm asking about.